# How to auto correct images size in this lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make [this lightbox](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) work on my website, but the images are not being displayed with their original sizes, [as you can see here](http://damontanha.com.br/Escalada-em-Rocha.html) (Click on "Galeria de fotos"). How can I write the following codes to correct this issue?

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
<div class="trip-tab-gallery">
<ul>
  <div class="column">
    <li><img src="images/tab-gallery-img-1.jpg" onclick="openModalhttps://s30.postimg.org/rxspwis5p/tab_gallery_img_1.jpgover-shadow">
  </li>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <li><img src="]https://s30.postimg.org/5n4uwjuvh/tab_gallery_img_2.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow">
  </li>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <li><img src="https://s30.postimg.org/h0vzlhurx/tab_gallery_img_3.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow">
  </li>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <li><img src="https://s30.postimg.org/eku67ncp9/tab_gallery_img_4.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow">
  </li>
  </div>
  </ul>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/rxspwis5p/tab_gallery_img_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="]https://s30.postimg.org/5n4uwjuvh/tab_gallery_img_2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/h0vzlhurx/tab_gallery_img_3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/eku67ncp9/tab_gallery_img_4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://s30.postimg.org/rxspwis5p/tab_gallery_img_1.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="]https://s30.postimg.org/5n4uwjuvh/tab_gallery_img_2.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://s30.postimg.org/h0vzlhurx/tab_gallery_img_3.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://s30.postimg.org/eku67ncp9/tab_gallery_img_4.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting max-width: 100% and height: auto; on the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that on all of the images, you have a width of 100%:

```
<img src="https://s30.postimg.org/5n4uwjuvh/tab_gallery_img_2.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Setting the width to 100% is forcing the image to expand to the size of the container. Changing this to **max-width** should fix that issue while also making sure the image doesn't go past the container.

```
<img src="https://s30.postimg.org/5n4uwjuvh/tab_gallery_img_2.jpg" style="max-width:100%">
```

After that, you can look into centering the image and making it look nice when it's small.

Side note: I noticed on some of the image URLs, there's a `[`, I'm guessing it's a typo?

UPDATE: To get the images aligned to the center and the background "removed":

Add the following CSS:

```
.mySlides{
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This'll set the background to black so that it won't look bad and align the picture to the center.

Comment: Hi h3raldo, thanks for your answer! I changed to "max-width:100%" as you said, but now I face another problem, the image is not on the center and there are a blank background on it. Have a look: https://s29.postimg.org/rpbb5h91j/Sem_t_tulo.png

Comment: About the "[" it was not supposed to be there, my mistake.

Comment: @TiagoKotryk, I've updated the answer so you can fix those two problems. Let me know if that works for ya!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, my problem with this lightbox is almost fixed, the only issue remaining is this one: https://s29.postimg.org/8uw3yz3jb/Sem_t_tulo.png any help with that would be great!

Comment: Nevermind, my code on my computer was missconf. Hahaha but do you know how to i can change the oppacity of the background?

Comment: Sure, just use `opacity: .5`, or whatever setting you'd like. If this answer worked for you, don't forget to mark it as accepted!